# Xcode 8 / swift 3 TextField character count

Tags: swift3, uitextfield

How do you count the characters in a textfield, I have not been able to find any methods that work with Swift 3.  Methods for strings apparently do not work on textfields.

Thank you

Comment: But they do work on the text field's text!

Comment: Matt: Could you give me an example?

Comment: You give _me_ an example. What have you tried?

Comment: cntt = (Name.text?.characters.count)!    This works I didn't have the PRENS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of characters in a string:

```
txtName.text!.count
```

Comment: Okay. Simpler: `txtName.text!.characters.count`

Comment: Yes its simpler

Comment: `.characters` is deprecated since Swift 3.2. use just `.count`

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4.0 & Swift 5.0

```
txtPassword.text!.count
```